# Debug my sqlite/content provier from mysql workbench?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm working with sqlite ehich contains more than 2000 rows.
i want to make sure that every insert/delete/update command was successfull.
is there a way to view the sqlite db in a run time? like watching databases with phpMyAdmin / MySQL WorkBench ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3 methods have a way to know:
Insert returns -1 if error occurs
Delete & update return the number of affected rows, or 0 if no rows are affected. You can extract the database from the emulator using DDMS view and view it using sqlite3.exe file found in the SDK folders